# Create a NET Core Project Reference to another project of a specific RID

Tags: c#, reflection, msbuild, .net-core, project-reference

Essientially I need to say:

```
<ProjectRefererence Target="../tool/tool.csproj">
    <RID>any</RID>
</ProjectReference>
```

where I need to specifically reference the "any" rid that is produced by `dotnet build` without the `-r`. Trying to reference a specific `rid` is guaranteed to not work. The default behavior is to build the dependent dll for the specific rid the current project is being built with. This *will not work*. The output assembly must be portable across architectures as it is loaded by reflection on potentially a different architecture it originated from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the project reference to include a global property that will override the defined value in the project (global properties from a command line or project reference will override properties statically defined in a project file):

```
<ItemGroup>
  <ProjectReference Include="..\ridspecificproj\ridspecificproj.csproj" Properties="RuntimeIdentifier=" />
</ItemGroup>
```

This will set `RuntimeIdentifier` to empty and the project will be built RID-independent.

Comment: Intellisense doesn't recognize a Properties attribute here and the only reference I can find for a Properties attribute on ProjectReference is this answer.

Comment: Yeah this is poorly documented but the way msbuild and its "common targets" work. There's also a `GlobalPropertiesToRemove` metadata item that is respected and helpful if you don't want to pass any commandline arguments to referenced projects.

Comment: The code is here: https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/blob/f0ee71c0d782cdf83693d1d14171800ec16650c1/src/Tasks/MSBuild.cs#L706-L708